# Can you programmatically create form fields in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

Supposing I have to display details on a form by reading an XML file, and according to the no. of elements I want to display the details in form. Is it possible to do so?

Ex:
 Say my XML file contains the following

```
<Rooms>
     <Room>
           <Name>A</Name>
           <ID>1</ID>
      </Room>
      <Room>
            <Name>B</Name>
            <ID>2</ID>
      </Room>
 </Rooms>
```

I can display the above details in the form. in case i add another room element to the xml file,

```
    <Room>
          <Name>C</Name>
          <ID>3</ID>
    <Room>
```

I want to display that too in the form. Is that actually possible? Any other alternatives?

Comment: another room element like <Room> <Name>C</Name><ID>3</ID></Room>

Comment: Yes. The code on how depends on whether you are talking about Web or WinForms or MVC or something else

Comment: It's certainly possible.

Comment: Yes you can. What have you tried?

Comment: what i've done is created form fields to display 10 rooms and have hidden the fields according to the room count.. but that's way too messy.

Comment: @Shee to get more interest and to stop more close-votes accumulating here - you should include in your question body what you're currently doing.  The SO community likes to know in these situations what you've done to try and solve the problem yourself; that gives us something to correct and improve on your behalf in the form of answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LINQ-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to parse the XML document, prepare a `List<T>` and show the result using *Controls* - like DataGridView, ListView etc.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation - translate your XML into strongly-typed objects (so a `Room` object with the given properties) which you can load into a collection of `List<Room>`.

Once you've got that, you now have the ability programmatically to add remove etc.

Now you need to bind your UI to that information - a cheap way will be to use the [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx) control - which, in conjunction with a data source, will automatically support editing and adding/re-ordering/deleting.

If you want something more complex, you can create a custom UserControl for the `Room` type, and then perhaps another to act as a container for a bunch of those.

I'm not going to post any code because I think there are so many options available to you - and you haven't really explained what you've tried - that to go much further would end up making this answer very long!  Want my advice - learn about the DataGridView first, how to customise the column formats and supply custom controls for that - it'll give you a good idea of what you might want from a fully roll-your-own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that is possible.

But the best option depends on what do you want to do with it. Are you going to edit the data? Or just show it? There are a number of options, you could show it in grid form, or like you suggested, create controls runtime. But then you would have to know what controls and maybe different controls for different data (labels or textboxes i.e. or is the texbox (in case of the ID) read-only. How are you going to determine those things? Also when you do create controls make sure you make it scrollable somehow, you don't know how much data you are getting so your form could become infinitely long!

For actually creating controls you could check: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319266

Comment: what i m actually doing is displaying the room id n room name n then a panel of combo box for the user to fill data into.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. Traditionally you would loop through your nodes in the Page_Init method of you aspx.cs file and user code similar to the psuedo code below:

```
foreach(//loop specified here) {
  Page.Form.Controls.Add(new TextBox() {Id = "Room" + loopValue});
}
```

Then on post back you should be able to access your dynamic controls using a similar loop to reconstruct the Id. This video should cover the concept in more detail.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-to-dynamically-add-controls-to-a-web-page